# How do I decide which convergence criterium to use and what to do if they don't work?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Take $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nn^{1/n} $$

I just blindly tried (Ratio test) $$ \limsup_{k\to\infty}  \left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right| $$ and (Root test) $$ \limsup_{k\to\infty}  \sqrt[k]{|a_k|} $$

Both yielded $1$ if I did them right, and $1$ is inconclusive. So I looked at the solution:

> The series over $ a_n = (-1)^n \sqrt[n]{n} $ is divergent, because $
>  \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: |a_n| \geq 1 $, $ a_n $ doesn't converge
>   towards zero.

Comment: It is not hard to show that **if** $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. So if $a_n$ does not have limit $0$, the series diverges. Showing the terms in our case don't have limit $0$ is trivial. They all have absolute value $\gt 1$.

Comment: Quotientenkriterium = ratio test; Wurzelkriterium=root test.

Answer (score 1):

The criteria you saw is called the ($n$th) term test. It says that for (complex or real) sequence $(a_n)$, if
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n
$$
converges, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0.
$$
In your problem, $(-1)^n \sqrt[n]{n}$ does not go to $0$, so by term test, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \sqrt[n]{n}$ diverges. Then how to show it diverges? If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n| =0$ and $\sqrt[n]{n}$ goes to $1$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) . Note that $$a_{2n} \rightarrow 1$$
$$a_{2n-1} \rightarrow -1$$

Answer (score 0):

if a series converge, $a_n \to 0$ as $ n\to \infty$. You can use this criterion to prove it doesn't converge since you know $|a_n| \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.